# How can I import issues from BitBucket to GitHub?

Tags: github, bug-trackers, bitbucket

I am trying to migrate a project from BitBucket to GitHub, and would like to import all the issues (preferably keeping their issue numbers intact).

Is there some tool or service which will accomplish this?

Answer (score 7):

This worked for me https://github.com/jeffwidman/bitbucket-issue-migration

```
python migrate.py -g username -u username -s reponame -d reponame
```

Comment: seems to only works for public repos

Comment: Also fails if you have 2FA enabled.

Comment: Didn't work even for public repositories

Comment: i recently took over maintenance of the bitbucket-issue-migration script. I fixed the bugs so it works fine for public repos, private repos are a planned feature in the next few weeks. 2FA is also supported via access tokens--it'll give you a helpful warning message if you try a 2FA account and just provide your normal password.

Comment: @JeffWidman thank you. Just saw the tool and this. Looking forward to the new release that supports private repo.

Comment: @JeffWidman thanks for the script! unfortunately I get the following error: https://gist.github.com/benoror/3ab1fe6ad3162426a157

Comment: FYI--the issue tracker is here: https://github.com/jeffwidman/bitbucket-issue-migration/issues/ Thanks @benoror for already moving your issue to the tracker.

Answer (score 2):

I just wrote a simple script in Ruby just to do that, you can check it out here: https://github.com/siong1987/issues_importer

Comment: It seems, that description of your script is very limited and I think, your code can only be used by an experienced Ruby developer. I found it very usable (the idea) and even thought about installing Ruby just for this one case. However, limited description proven me, that I'm not going to use it, as I have lack of knowledge. Any chance you can extend the description (format of `.rb` file, what, how and when should be run etc.) or introduce some simple wiki for that repo?

Comment: @trejder i just updated the documentation.  it is actually as easier as that.

Comment: I'm on Windows and after spending a decent chunk of time trying to get it to run, I'm not sure why running `bundle install` causes nokogiri (1.6.1) to not get compiled. I see libiconv, libxslt, libxml-2.0 are not found in the mkmf.log file.

Answer (score 0):

I found it critical to be able to repeat the migration without causing any havoc.
Therefore, I suggest to use this script, which allows to do subsequent tweaks after running the initial issue migration:

https://github.com/fkirc/bitbucket-issues-to-github